# Login form redirect

Tags: php

I have a login button of type submit on page 1. It redirects to page 2.

- if the username field entered is correct (exists in the database), I want to go to a page with welcome user and some other buttons.
- else go to a page with access denied and link to page 1 again

PAGE 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>

</head>
<body  style="background-color:lightgrey">

    <form name="input" action="page2.php" method="post">
Username:<br/> <input type="text" name="username" />  <br />  

Password: <br/> <input type="text" name="password" />  <br />  

    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </form>

      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","111");
    if (!$con)
     {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     mysql_select_db("trial", $con);


$usertext=$_POST["username"];

$passwordtext=$_POST["password"];

$myusers = mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM users", $con);


$found=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myusers))
{
if($usertext== $row['Username'])
{

    $found=1;
}

 }

 if($found==1)
 {

//GO TO ANOTHER PAGE????


}
else 
{ //GO TO ANOTHER PAGE????
 echo "FAIL"; 

   }

    mysql_close($con);



?>
```

Comment: What's your question? How to redirect the browser to another page?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I can not put a form tag with buttons inside it in the php part ..

Comment: if the username is entered correctly or wrong, in both cases i direct to page 2.... can i then control what appears on page 2?

Comment: I don't think you need php tag over here. I think you just need to redirect to different page. If your user authentication is correct, you just need to redirect to your welcome page else redirect to your error page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

Comment: If you will be displaying some **private** data ONLY for logged-in users, please read my answer - it will save your time pulling hair off the head

Answer (score 0):

**Dont go with only redirects**, because **anyone can enter the second** page URL at the browser address bar.
If you must ensure the data you show on the second page is secure, displayed to only logged in users use sessions - add `session_start();` at the script start.
If user logins correctly do: `$_SESSION['logged']=true;`
otherwise: `$_SESSION['logged']=false;`

At the second page use `session_start();` once more.
Then check if the user is logged by checking `$_SESSION['logged']` variable.

```
if($_SESSION['logged']==true){
   echo 'private data'; //or include some file for example require 'data.html';
}else{
   session_destroy();
   unset($_SESSION);
   echo 'go, and login again!';
}
```

Also, you should probably redirect the user from the login page to the private data if he is already logged in:

```
if($_SESSION['logged']==true){
   header('Location: second_form.php');
}
```

Another thing with your snippet is that you never check for valid password :>
OK, another **SECURITY VIOLATION** is

```
usertext=$_POST["username"];

$passwordtext=$_POST["password"];
```

Please, sanitize your input. **Anyone can damage your database** without it([SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) - do it this way:

```
usertext=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);

$passwordtext=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
```